# Go to start of search string after `RET`

Tags: isearch

What's the best way to move point to the start of an `isearch` result instead of the end?

E.g. given the following, where `|` is point:

```
|foo bar baz
```

And searching for `bar`, I'd like point to be at:

```
foo |bar baz
```

instead of

```
foo bar| baz
```

The latter is almost never useful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't want the same behavior on `isearch-backward`:

```el
(defun isearch-exit--after ()
  (when isearch-forward
    (setf (point) isearch-other-end)))
(advice-add 'isearch-exit :after 'isearch-exit--after)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. So `isearch-backward` puts point at the *beginning* of the result? Super weird!

Comment: Not weird. The defaults are such that another search in the same direction for the same pattern will not find *the same match you found last time*.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense...however, it seems that this information could simply be held in some variable (`isearch` doesn't shy away from state anyway).